# why my API that uses fetch to send an email produces an undefined response but still send the email successfully

Tags: node.js, express, google-api, google-oauth, server-side-rendering

I'm building a simple server for receiving emails, the `useFetch()` method throws an error because of this line `const data = await response.json();` it tells me "**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')**", although I'm using the same code exactly on another program.
the weird thing is the last time I tested this program it didn't produce any errors. Also, It can still send emails.

here is the method that calls `useFetch()` :

```
import { useFetch } from "./fetchData.js";

export const sendEmail = async (data) => {


  try {
    const result = await useFetch("/sendEmail", data);

    if(result.status === "success")
     {
        console.log("ok");
        /* code to inform the user that the email was sent*/
        setTimeout(() => location.assign("/"), 1.5 * 1000);
        
     }

     if (result.status !== "success") return;
     
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    
  }
};
```

`useFetch()` method:

```
const timeout = () => {
  new Promise((_, reject) => {
    setTimeout(
      () => reject(Error("Something went wrong, please try again")),
      5000
    );
  });
};

export const useFetch = async (url, emailData) => {
  
  try {
    const request = fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify(emailData),
        });
                
    const response = await Promise.race([request, timeout(),]);
        
    const data = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) throw Error(data.message);
    
    return data;

    
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.message === "Failed to fetch")
      error.message = `Unable to reach the server. Please check your internet connection...`;
    throw error;
  }
};
```

a screenshot of the error :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to understand what code is doing and how it behaves:

`const response = await Promise.race([request, timeout(),]);`

[Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) is an static function which settles whenever any of the iterables promises provided resolves in it which means either request or timeout whatever resolves first your code will move to next line to execute it. Now, if any promise failed in it, it will settle and won't return anything and thats why `const data = await response.json()` failed.

Now, when you say the email is sent because you sent the request and it processed the email but resolved it later and your code didn't wait as you didn't ask it to.

What you expect from a code is to cancel the request if it takes long. You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667981/halt-execution-of-network-request-if-it-takes-too-long).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive explanation. I thought that maybe the problem was because of `race()` so I tried to increase the value of `timeout()` but that didn't change a thing. I removed it completely now to be just `const response = await request;`